# AngularJS : How to get models from custom directive in controller?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying getting the dynamic model being added within custom directive to be accessed in the controller:

My view is like this :

```
<form ng-submit="updateConfigData()" novalidate class="form-horizontal" name="questionnaires">
    <accordion close-others="true">

                    <!--Show segment questions-->
                    <accordion-group ng-repeat="(key, question) in segment.questions" id="q_{{question.q_id}}"> 
                        <accordion-heading>{{question.q_title}}</accordion-heading>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <custom-question qdata="question"></custom-question>
                        </div>
                    </accordion-group>

                </accordion>
</form>
```

My custom directive is like this :

```
ModuleConfigQuestions.directive('customQuestion',function($compile,$sce){
  return{
    restrict:'E',
    scope: {qdata: '='},
    require: '?ngModel', // get a hold of NgModelController
    link:function(scope, element, attribute,ngModel){
      if(!ngModel) return; // do nothing if no ng-model

      var q_data = scope.qdata;

      var arr_keys = [];
      var arr_values = [];
      /*
      answers: {13: "Yes",14: "No"}
      Covert answers into separate array of
      */
      for (var key in q_data.answers) {
        if (q_data.answers.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            arr_values.push(q_data.answers[key]);
            arr_keys.push(key);
        }
      }  

      var el = angular.element('<div>');;
      /*Make template for BOOL Type question*/
      switch( q_data.q_type ){

        case ANSWER_TYPE_BOOL :
          el.append(arr_values[0]+'&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="'+q_data.q_id+'" ng-model="formdata['+q_data.q_id+']" value="'+arr_keys[0]+'" />&nbsp;&nbsp;');
          el.append(arr_values[1]+'&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="'+q_data.q_id+'" ng-model="formdata['+q_data.q_id+']" value="'+arr_keys[1]+'" />');
        break;

      }
      $compile(el)(scope);
      element.append(el);
      // Specify how UI should be updated
      /*ngModel.$render = function() {
        element.html($sce.getTrustedHtml(ngModel.$viewValue || ''));

      };*/

    }
  };
});
```

My controller is like this :

```
ModuleConfigQuestions.controller('ctrlListQuestionnaires',function ($location,$scope,$http,$rootScope,$cookies,ServiceCheckAuth,ServiceConfigData){
    /*First check patient is logged in*/
    if( !ServiceCheckAuth.isPatientLoggedIn() ){ 
        $location.url('/login'); 
        return;
    }
    /*Set rootScope values*/
    $rootScope.root = {
        html_title:HTML_TITLE_PATIENT_QUESTIONNAIRES,
        loggedin:true,
        activeQeuestionaires:'active'
    };

    $scope.formdata = {};

    ServiceConfigData.getConfigData($scope,SECTION_BASIC_QUES);
    $scope.updateConfigData = function(){
        console.log( $scope.formdata );
    }

});
```

As you can see in the controller I'm assuming all model values to be append in formdata object when form gets submitted.

But this is not working as it should, Any one out there who can point out what fundamental thing I'm missing ?

Note : I've read about the using ngModelController but can't figure how it should be applied.

Comment: can you make jsfiddle

Comment: Here is plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/u7EHOsqVzjUFXIrrrSuy?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
// Code goes here


var ModuleConfigQuestions = angular.module('ModuleConfigQuestions',
 [ 
  'ngRoute',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ui.bootstrap'
 ]
 );
 
ModuleConfigQuestions.directive('customQuestion',function($compile,$sce){
  return{
    restrict:'E',
    scope: {qdata: '='},
    link:function(scope, element, attribute){
      var q_data = scope.qdata;
      var arr_keys = [];
      var arr_values = [];
      
      /*
      answers: {13: "Yes",14: "No"}
      Covert answers into separate array of
      */
      for (var key in q_data.answers) {
        if (q_data.answers.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            arr_values.push(q_data.answers[key]);
            arr_keys.push(key);
        }
      }  

      var el = angular.element('<div>');
      /*Make template for BOOL Type question*/
      switch( q_data.q_type ){

        case 'bool' :
          el.append(arr_values[0]+'&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="'+q_data.q_id+'" ng-model="$parent.formdata['+q_data.q_id+']" value="'+arr_keys[0]+'" />&nbsp;&nbsp;');
          el.append(arr_values[1]+'&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="'+q_data.q_id+'" ng-model="$parent.formdata['+q_data.q_id+']" value="'+arr_keys[1]+'" />');
        break;

      }
      $compile(el)(scope);
      element.append(el);


    }
  };
}); 



ModuleConfigQuestions.controller('ctrlListQuestionnaires',function ($location,$scope,$http,$rootScope,$cookies){
    
    $scope.formdata = {};
    
    $scope.questions = 
    [
        {q_id:1,q_title:'First',q_type:'bool',answers:{13:'Yes',14:'No'} },
        {q_id:2,q_title:'Second',q_type:'bool',answers:{15:'Yes',16:'No'} }
    ]
    
    
    
    $scope.updateConfigData = function(){
        console.log( $scope.formdata );
    }

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.1" data-semver="1.4.1" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.1/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://dev.simplifi.org/patients/js/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://dev.simplifi.org/patients/js/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://dev.simplifi.org/patients/js/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    
    <form ng-app="ModuleConfigQuestions" ng-controller="ctrlListQuestionnaires" ng-submit="updateConfigData()" novalidate class="form-horizontal" name="questionnaires">
    <accordion close-others="true">

                    <!--Show segment questions-->
                    <accordion-group ng-repeat="(key, question) in questions" id="q_{{question.q_id}}"> 
                        <accordion-heading>{{question.q_title}}</accordion-heading>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <custom-question qdata="question"></custom-question>
                        </div>
                    </accordion-group>

                </accordion>
                <br>
                <br>
                
                <input type="submit" vakue="Submit" />
</form>
    
    
  </body>

</html>
```

You need to use `$parent` to access the controller's scope in this situation. There are various other ways to access a Controller's scope from a directive, but in this case `$parent` is the simplest solution.

Comment: :O :( That simple ??? I was just missing $parent ....  I'm very grateful to you sir :-) thanks a lot....

Comment: Your welcome! It's usually the simple fixes that are the hardest to spot.

Comment: Is there anything other help you need with this issue @AngularLearner ?

Comment: @AngularLearner if you found this helpful would you mind accepting my answer please?